# Notation v+U (vector + vector space)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

I came across a notation: $\mathbf{v} + U$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector in $V$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. What does this notation mean? I've only seen sum of vector spaces but not vector + vector space?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context, but sometimes $\vec v+U$ refers to the set

$$\vec v + U := \{\vec v+\vec u:\space \vec u \in U\}$$

Note that this set is not necessarily a subspace if $U$ is a subspace.